# Set, Multiset, Map, Multimap

Tags: c++

В чем разница между ними и примеры, если можно.

Comment: Может кому-то пригодиться при написании ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237361/how-sets-multisets-maps-and-multimaps-work-internally

Comment: Вам дествительно нужен пухлый ответ со всеми деталями, или может сможете конкретизировать вопрос?

Answer (score 4):

**Отличие `Set` от `Map`**

1. `Set` хранит набор объектов; от массива и `std::vector` отличается более быстрой скоростью извлечения.
2. `Map` является *ассоциативным массивом*, то есть мы запрашиваем *ключ*, а получаем *значение* (то есть полезную нагрузку ключа).

**Теперь о `Multi...`**

Варианты контейнеров с этим названием позволяют хранить:

- несколько одинаковых элементов (в случае с `Multiset`),
- либо несколько значений с одинаковыми ключами, но разной полезной нагрузкой (в случае с `Multimap`).

Одинаковость элементов определяется с помощью *операции равенства* (`operator==`). То есть переопределяя этот оператор для всего хранимого типа данных, либо конкретного контейнера, можно изменить критерий равенства элементов.